# Meaning of "Man of your talents"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

It's a line in Star War Rogue One.

```
- You are a hard man to find, Galen.
- But farming...
- Really? Man of your talents?
```

What does "Man of your talents?" mean?

Is man a verb or noun here? What does man mean?

Comment: @Max No, Galen is a scientist, escaping from the speaker.

Comment: well.. is that important? What you are asking seems to verify the usage I'm asking is quite irregular...

Comment: [Galen Walton Erso](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galen_Walton_Erso) is not building Death Stars like Krennic wants him to, but is instead hiding from the Empire as a farmer. What he is farming is irrelevant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Man" here is a noun. We can imagine the full version of the sentence as something like this:

> How can a man of your talents think of farming? You should be engaged in something more intellectual.

I did not see the movie, so I've restored the implied meaning based on your short excerpt. The real implied meaning may be different, based on the larger context.

Comment: Wow, awesome, it omits a lot!!